# mutidimensional local homeomorphism and inverse map

Tags: general-topology

Let $f: X^N \to Y$ be a continuous function such that $f(x_1, \cdots, x_{N-1}, \cdot): X\to Y$ is a local homeomorphism. Is it true that there exists a continuous function $h: X^{N-1}\times Y \to X$ such that
$$
f(x_1,\cdots, x_{N-1}, h(x_1,\cdots, x_{N-1}, y))=y ?
$$
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So in particular for $N=1$ you ask whether a local homeomorphism $f:X\to Y$ always has a one sided inverse $Y\to X$. This is not true. And additional variables don't change much (the same counterexample for $N=1$ can be lifted to any $N$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **freakish** said in the comments, there are counterexamples already when $N=1$. Let $f:\Bbb R\to S^1:x\mapsto e^{ix}$; this is easily seen to be a local homeomorphism that just wraps $\Bbb R$ repeatedly around the unit circle. Let $h:S^1\to\Bbb R$ be any continuous map. Then $h[S^1]$ is a compact, connected subset of $\Bbb R$, so there are $a,b\in\Bbb R$ such that $a\le b$, and $h[S^1]=[a,b]$. Clearly $f\circ h\ne\mathrm{id}_{S^1}$ if $a=b$, so assume that $a<b$, and let $p,q\in S^1$ be such that $h(p)=a$ and $h(q)=b$. Let $C_0$ and $C_1$ be the two closed arcs of $S^1$ with endpoints $p$ and $q$; then $h[C_0]=[a,b]=h[C_1]$. Let $x\in(a,b)$; there are $u\in C_0$ and $v\in C_1$ such that $h(u)=h(v)=x$. Then $(f\circ h)(u)=f(x)=(f\circ h)(v)$, and $u\ne v$, so either $(f\circ h)(u)\ne u$, or $(f\circ h)(v)\ne v$, and again $f\circ h\ne\mathrm{id}_{S^1}$.